# Using ASP.NET, how can I write part of title in master page while another part in content page?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website using ASP.NET. I want titles of my web page in this form:

```
<page name> - <site name>
```

e.g.:

```
Home - Stack Overflow
```

Can I write `- <site name>` part in the master page? While `<page name>` part in content page?

I have tried write this in master page, but not work:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="placeHolder_title" runat="server"/> - Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
```

And this in content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="content_title" ContentPlaceHolderID="placeHolder_title" runat="server">Home</asp:Content>
```

Only a `Home` is displayed.

Comment: I imagine that should work but what if you close you placeholder like this? `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="placeHolder_title" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         Page.Title = "MyPageName - " + Page.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is maintaining literal strings in the code like that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `Literal` in this case, and specify the `Text` property to that of the default (say, site name), and adjust for other pages:

```
<title><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TitleLiteral" Text="Site Name" /></title>
```

Then you can have the Master page check the `Title` property value of the current page and apply it.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title)) {
  TitleLiteral.Text = Title + " - " + TitleLiteral.Text;
}
```

Presuming the "home" page doesn't have a title, that will just show the default value, those pages that do have a title value will prepend it.

Comment: @Downvoter Not my usual course of action, but I urge you to tell me what you think is wrong with this answer, as, quite simply, it's not (AFAIK) and even provides a less coupled mechanism than the other.